# I can no longer update my django content

Tags: django

My app has broken. I am following a tutorial and I am able to create posts. But when I try to edit them I get the following error

```
NoReverseMatch at /posts/16/edit/
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('1', '6')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P<id>\\d+)/$']
```

If I try to edit my older posts I created a couple of days ago, I don't get this error. I do not know what I have done while I was following this tutorial to break it

heres my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import *


urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$',   post_list, name='list'),
  url(r'^create$', post_create, name='create'),
  url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
  url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
  url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', post_delete, name='delete'),
]
```

heres my views

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.


def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()

        messages.success(request, "Created !!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts:list'))
    else:
        messages.error(request, "not Created !!")
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "title": "Create Form"
    }
    return render(request, "posts/post_form.html", context)


def post_detail(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance
    }
    return render(request, "posts/post_detail.html", context)


def post_list(request):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
            "queryset": queryset,
            "title": "My user List",
        }


    return render(request, "posts/base.html", context)


def post_update(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "saved !!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts:detail', args=id))

    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "posts/post_form.html", context)


def post_delete(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    instance.delete()
    messages.success(request, "Deleted !!")
    return redirect('posts:list')
```

heres my post_detail.html

```
{% extends "posts/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p><a href='{% url "posts:list" %}'>Back</a></p>
    <p><a href='{% url "posts:delete" instance.id %}'>delete</a></p>


        <h3>{{instance.title}}</h3>
        <p>{{instance.content}}</p>
        <p>{{instance.timestamp}}</p>
        <p>{{instance.updated}}</p>
        <p>{{instance.id}}</p>

{% endblock content %}
```

heres my post_form.html

```
{% extends "posts/base.html" %}


    {% block content %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <h1>Edit: {{ title }}</h1>
    <form method='post' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create Post">
    </form>
    {% endblock content %}}
```

heres my base.html

```
<html>



<body>
   {% if messages %}
   <div class="messages">
<ul class="messages">
   {% for message in messages %}
   <li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}" {% endif %} >{{ message }}   </li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
```

{% endif %}

```
<div class="container">
{% block content %}

    <p>parent page</p>


    <h1>{{ title }} is working</h1>

    {% for p in queryset %}
        <a href='{% url "posts:detail" p.id %}'>
            <h3>{{p.title}}</h3>
        </a>

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href='{% url "posts:update" p.id %}'>edit</a>
        <a href='{% url "posts:delete" p.id %}'>delete</a>
    {% endif %}
        <p>{{p.content}}</p>
        <p>{{p.timestamp}}</p>
        <p>{{p.updated}}</p>
        <p>{{p.id}}</p>
    <hr>
    {% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

my traceback

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/posts/16/edit/

Django Version: 1.9.1
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'posts.apps.PostsConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/ray/Desktop/mypy/trydjango/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/ray/Desktop/mypy/trydjango/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/ray/Desktop/mypy/trydjango/src/posts/views.py" in post_update
  63.         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts:detail', args=id))

File "/Users/ray/Desktop/mypy/trydjango/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/Users/ray/Desktop/mypy/trydjango/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /posts/16/edit/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('1', '6')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P<id>\\d+)/$']
```

Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app isnt broken, it is just a bug in the code you need to resolve. 
Your issue is here:

```
reverse('posts:detail', args=id)
```

should be

```
reverse('posts:detail', args=(id, )) #or even args=[id]
```

`args` is expecting a list, and since you sent it "16", it is being interpreted as ["1", "6"] and nothing matches that pattern.

By explicitly sending a list, you can make sure the `id` being sent is indeed "16" and not a list.

You can read more on [this in the `documentation here`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

Comment: Thank you immensly. Thats what fixed the problem. Now I see why the previous ones were working, They were single digits.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts:detail', args=id))
```

Try with:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts:detail', args=[id]))
```